# bitcoind performance issues

Tags: bitcoind, performance

I am struggling with poor performance of Bitcoin Core full node, which is used as a hot wallet.

There are similar questions already but without an answer or solution

- [Bitcoind Performance for production usage](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/23717/bitcoind-performance-for-production-usage)
- [Bitcoind has too slow API call performance on large wallets](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/41813/bitcoind-has-too-slow-api-call-performance-on-large-wallets)
- ...?

Bitcoin core is freshly installed about a month ago (version 24.0.1), new wallet is created on that node a few weeks ago as well. This wallet is a HD wallet and it uses "descriptors" format (not the legacy one).

I generated about 300k addresses from this wallet and imported about 10k private keys in the descriptor format.

The wallet responds quite quick overall but sometimes it stuck and almost any call last for tens of seconds or for minutes. `getbalances`, `listtransactions`, etc.

Also, `validateaddress` util call last for tens of seconds and it leads to read timeouts in my applications.

There is an example of that issue (with legacy address):

```
$ time bitcoin-cli validateaddress 1Hv...qK 
{
  "isvalid": true,
  "address": "1Hv...qK",
  "scriptPubKey": "76a9...88ac",
  "isscript": false,
  "iswitness": false
}

real    0m46,627s
user    0m0,007s
sys     0m0,000s
```

During that time, `b-httpworker.X` consumes 100 % CPU and there is no peak in IO nor RAM usage. **If I repeat that call afterwards, it returns the response instantly**.

`validateaddress` should just check the address format, shouldn't it? I don't understand why it last so long and what does it do during that time. debug log is, sadly, empty.

Does anyone has a clue what is going on? How should I debug such problems?

Thanks for help.

Comment: I had finally found some clues. Github issue [#27002](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/27002) seems related to my problem and there is also possible fix/performance improvement in pull request [#26008](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/26008).